# How to get the contents of the body tag of the page through the browser extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why is variable body empty? how to get body tag content?

> I am writing code for google chrome extension. I plan to use the
> extension for personal use only. For web scraping.
> To finally analyze the text. I want to play with text.

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
 
    if(document.readyState == "complete"){
        
        var url = changeInfo.url;
        // I want to save the url to a file(url.txt)
        
        var body = document.body.innerText;
        // why is body empty?????
        
        var pattern = /[A-Z].*?\./g;
        var result = text.match(pattern);
        result.forEach(myFunction);

        function myFunction(item) {
        text += item+"\n"; 
        }
        // I want to save the text to a file(collection.txt)
       

    }
     
 });
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Parser",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `manifest.json` you posted it looks like you are running your code as a background script.

Background scripts don't have direct access to the loaded page content - this is why the body is empty in your code.

Instead, you will need to use a content script to access the page content and then message that data across to your background script for processing.

Here is an example setup using a background and content script that should let you retrieve and process the page content when a tab loads (not tested, but should point you in the right direction).

Thanks to the [ResourceOverride extension](https://github.com/kylepaulsen/ResourceOverride) which I used as a reference for writing the example below.

**background.js**

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender){
    
    if (!message || typeof message !== 'object' || !sender.tab){
        // Ignore messages that weren't sent by our content script.
        return;
    }
    
    switch (message.action){
        case 'receiveBodyText': {
            processBodyText(sender.tab, message.bodyText);
            break;
        }
    }
});

function processBodyText(tab, bodyText){
    
    var url = tab.url;
    // I want to save the url to a file(url.txt)
    
    // TODO: Process your bodyText
    
    var pattern = /[A-Z].*?\./g;
    var result = text.match(pattern);
    result.forEach(myFunction);

    function myFunction(item) {
        text += item+"\n"; 
    }
    // I want to save the text to a file(collection.txt)
}
```

**content.js**

```
// content.js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    let bodyText = document.body.innerText;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: 'receiveBodyText',
        bodyText: bodyText
    });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Parser",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches" : [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

---

#### Information and docs

A note on WebExtension API differences between firefox and chrome:

> Chrome uses the `chrome` namespace, Firefox uses the future-standard `browser` namespace.
>
> So code written in Chrome would use: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated(...)`
> and the equivalent in Firefox would be: `browser.tabs.onUpdated(...)`
>
> Be aware of that when reading the docs and reading example extensions.

- **Background scripts**

  - do not have access to the loaded page
  - have full access to the WebExtensions API
- **Content scripts**

  - have full access to the loaded page
  - have only limited access to the WebExtensions API
  - [Chrome content scripts docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)
  - [MDN content scripts docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts)
  - Docs on [communication between content scripts and background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#communicating_with_background_scripts)
- **WebExtensions API**

  - [Chrome WebExtensions API reference](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/)
  - [MDN WebExtensions API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API)
- **other useful links**

  - [MDN WebExtensions example Github repository](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples)
  - [MDN "Anatomy of a WebExtension"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension)
  - [MDN detailed browser WebExtensions support tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs)
  - [ResourceOverride extension](https://github.com/kylepaulsen/ResourceOverride) - this is a fairly complex extension that uses both background and content scripts. I this used as a reference/example to better understand how extensions are written.